# Difference between IF in Python vs Template block?

Tags: python, if-statement, templates, flask, jinja2

Trying to if condition to set variable. Guessing this is merely a formatting issue difference between Python and Python-in-templates.

```
{% block main_nested_b scoped %}
{% for user in list_users %}
{% set t_id_user = user[0][0] %}
{% set t_email = user[7][0] %}
{% set t_email_show = t_email %}
<!-- ERROR from 3 lines below -->
{% if (len(t_email_show) >= 18):
        set t_email_show = t_email_show[:18]
    endif %}
```

Error message:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'set'
```

p.s. I realize I can truncate that `t_email` variable without even using an IF but I want to understand how to use IF differently within a template.

Help?

Comment: The same answer: separate tags. `{% if ... %}` (no `:`!), then `{% set ... %}`.

Comment: and you don't need the `if` here *at all*, just use `{% set t_email_show = t_email[:18] %}`. as slicing will not throw an error or make a shorter string longer.

Comment: A note of terminology: you are not writing Python here. Not even "Python in templates*. You are writing [Jinja template syntax](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/). The syntax borrows heavily from Python syntax but only in that *expressions* are a lot like Python expressions. Jinja2k is *a different language* altogether.